# Difference between presentModalViewController and pushViewController regarding memory management

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, modal-dialog, pushviewcontroller

Although I've solved this problem. I *really* need someone to explain to me why it worked.

I've got a `UINavBar` that has a custom `UIView` as the visible ViewController. I created a custom button in place of the navbar's title view and set it as `autorelease` (I'm customising existing non-ARC [code](http://www.research.ibm.com/remail/)):

```
- (void)loadView {
    ..  

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(presentEmailThreadList)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 of %d",self.numThreads] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

    self.navigationItem.titleView = [button autorelease];
}
```

This code works when I present a view modally ie:

```
[self presentModalViewController:emailThreadListVC animated:YES];
```

but gives me an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error if I try to push it to the navigation stack, then click the 'back button' on the new VC:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:emailThreadListVC animated:YES];
```

and specifically crashes at the `UINavigationItemTitleView`:

[image]

I've concluded that the `titleView` no longer exists when I try to go back to the original VC, meaning that the `autorelease` did decrement the reference count on the `titleView` when I push a VC ontop the stack, but it won't decrement the reference count when I push a VC modally.

Any idea why?

Comment: Remember that a modal window is modal - the system knows you're coming back at some point, so this could perhaps be why it maintains the reference count.

Comment: could you show how you create `button` (re. memory management)?

Comment: @sergio sure just updated the code (there is nothing special though I don't think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
...
self.navigationItem.titleView = [button autorelease];  <-- DOUBLE AUTORELEASE
```

`buttonWithType` already returns an autoreleased object, so you do not need to explicitly autorelease it again.

Why it works when you use `presentViewController` is another issue. I think it comes down to different timings in the two cases.